# Namenode doesn't detect datanodes failure

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have set up a Hadoop high available cluster including 3 nodes as masters (3 journal nodes, active namenode, and standby namenode, with no secondary namenode) and 3 datanodes.
using commands

`hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode
 hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
 hadoop-daemon.sh start zkfc`

I start namenode services and using command `hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode` I start datanode services.

The problem is when I stop a datanode intentionally using command `hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode`, In the namenodes WebUI,(both active and standby) even after some minutes, it is still considered as an alive node and I think namenodes don't detect datanode's failure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers, from [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/2474/how-to-identify-stale-datanode.html):

A datanode is considered stale when:

> dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval < last contact < (2 *
>   dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval)

In the NameNode UI Datanodes tab, a stale datanode will stand out due to having a larger value for the Last contact among live datanodes (also available in JMX output). When a datanode is stale, it will be given lowest priority for reads and writes.

Using default values, the namenode will consider a datanode stale when its heartbeat is absent for 30 seconds. After another 10 minutes without a heartbeat (10.5 minutes total), a datanode is considered dead.

Relevant properties include:

```
dfs.heartbeat.interval - default: 3 seconds
dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval - default: 30 seconds
dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval - default: 5 minutes
dfs.namenode.avoid.read.stale.datanode - default: true
dfs.namenode.avoid.write.stale.datanode - default: true
```